# Is DependcenyProperty always inherited?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

Is there a mechanism that is blocking the inheritance of DependecyProperty or some values are set locally by some elements?

I have two examples that I don't understand:

```
<Button Background="AntiqueWhite" Height="40" Width="50" FontSize="10">
   <Button>Test</Button>            
</Button>

<TextBlock Text="Test" Background="AntiqueWhite" Height="40" Width="50" FontSize="10">
        <TextBlock />            
</TextBlock>
```

In Button element the child button is not inheriting background / height / width but it is inheriting fontsize even though all of the properties are DependencyProperty.

In TextBlock element situation is the same but we have another DependencyProperty (Text).

I understand how priorities work. Local value has greater priority over Inherited one. But where can i get information if a control sets something by itself? Or maybe there is some other mechanism that is preventing some DependencyProperties from being inherited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms751554%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

`DependencyProperties` have `PropertyMetadata` (relevant class is `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`)

One of the flags described is the `Inherits` flag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.inherits%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Excerpt:

> Inherits. By default, dependency properties do not inherit values.
>   OverridesInheritanceBehavior allows the pathway of inheritance to also
>   travel into a visual tree, which is necessary for some control
>   compositing scenarios. NoteNote
>
> The term "inherits" in the context of property values means something
>   specific for dependency properties; it means that child elements can
>   inherit the actual dependency property value from parent elements
>   because of a WPF framework-level capability of the WPF property
>   system. It has nothing to do directly with managed code type and
>   members inheritance through derived types. For details, see Property
>   Value Inheritance.

Comment: Is there any "easy" way to check that flags? In the link you mentioned they wrote some code. I thought information like that would be shown at description of each property at msdn.

Comment: @Morfidon I am not aware of a tool directly, but you should be able to use a reflector to see the source of a FrameworkElement having meta data. A free one is `JetBrains dotPeek` for instance (and its cool too :)). A static button ctor overrides some metadata for instance: FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (Button), (PropertyMetadata) new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object) typeof (Button)));